# Отправка данных не поступает в базу данных, пересмотрел код 10 раз, не могу найти ошибку

Tags: php, mysql

Это код create_user.html, сама форма регистрация и отправка данных в create_user.php.
[image: Сама форма регистрации и отправка в create_user.php]

Это код create_user.php отправка данных в бд
[image: Код create_user.php]

Comment: Доброе утро. Смотрите ошибки в логах, консоли браузера. Проверьте, включён ли вывод ошибок и какой уровень.

Comment: Замените картинки кодом как текст.

Comment: @slo_nik Так у меня даже не проходит до create_user.php

Comment: На Ваших картинках трудно разобрать текст. Замените на обычный код. И смотрите логи, включайте вывод ошибок в браузер.

Comment: Как вы это поняли ? И если он не вызывается, значит браузер отправляет запрос куда то не туда. Включите отладку запросов в браузере (для Chrome - вкладка Network режима разработчика) и посмотрите какой запрос он шлет на сервер. после этого смотрите в логах сервера, пришел ли запрос туда и не появилось ли при этом что нибудь в error_log

Comment: @slo_nik 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OSPanel\domains\newp\scripts\database_connection.php:5) in C:\OSPanel\domains\newp\scripts\create_user.php on line 32

Comment: Это распространённая ошибка, решений в google масса. Вы делаете вывод до отправки заголовков. Вот Вам куча решений https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=Warning%3A+Cannot+modify+header+information+-+headers+already+sent+by

Comment: @slo_nik Спасибо большое:)